# AWS S3 + cross account file download failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have created a bucket called (apple-bucket) in "AWS account 1"  and given access to another "AWS account 2"  to upload files to apple-bucket.

File upload is successful from "aws account 2"  to account 1 bucket.

Where as when I download the file from  S3 (apple-bucket) I get access denied in the console.

my bucket policy is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::******:role/role-name",
                    "arn:aws:iam::******:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::apple-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::apple-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Access1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::apple-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::apple-bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: From command line  I am able to download file using "QA AWS credentials" but not with "PROD AWS" credentials.

Comment: What do you mean by "QA AWS Account"? Do you mean a role, or an actual AWS account? If it is an account, which user are you using *within* the account? What do you mean by "upload is successful from QA account to Prod bucket" -- how are you uploading from an "account"? You also talk about "QA AWS credentials" and "Prod AWS credentials" -- are these credentials for IAM Users or Root credentials? Feel free to Edit your question to clarify.

Comment: The policy you have shown is granting everybody in whole world access to your `apple-bucket`. If you claim that it is not working, please Edit your question and include examples of the commands that are failing, and the error shown.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it looks, to me, like what's being overlooked is an aspect of S3 permissions that is documented but perhaps not in explicit terms of its full implications: specifically, when A creates an object in B's bucket, A owns the object... and B's bucket policy lacks authority to grant permissions on objects in B's bucket that are owned by A unless A grants `bucket-owner-full-control` when creating the object, thereby delegating authority to B and making the bucket policy applicable.  What do you think?

Comment: Ah! Yes, that could fit the description from @Vinod. Can be solved by passing `bucket-owner-full-control` at the time of upload, or by doing an in-place COPY on all the objects to add this permission. (Might need to use Root credentials to do that, or do it from the entity that did the upload.)

Answer (score 1):

As Michael and John have discussed (in the comments), you can correct S3 object ACLs by copying over existing objects or avoid the download issue by ensuring ACLs are correctly set on upload.

I recently had to contend with this issue on a fairly large scale (millions of objects without proper ACLs). After having to bear the time and expense of in-place copies for all these objects, I put a bucket policy in place to ensure that all objects uploaded to the bucket are required to grant `bucket owner full control`.

This example policy shows how to allow a specific AWS account to upload objects to your bucket while requiring the proper object ACLs:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowSourceAccount0123456789ToPutObjects",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::0123456789:root"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::apple-bucket/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "RequireAllUploadedObjectsToAssignFullControlToBucketOwner",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::apple-bucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

The key is the explicit deny which checks for the `x-amz-acl: bucket-owner-full-control` header and fails any upload where this is not set. When using the AWS CLI to upload files this requires the **--acl bucket-owner-full-control** flag to be set.

Example:

`aws s3 cp example-file.txt s3://apple-bucket/example-file.txt --profile aws-profile-name --acl bucket-owner-full-control`